# Is it possible to link to a sub menu of your apps settings.bundle on iOS8?

Tags: ios8, settings.bundle

Using **UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString** gives the URL

```
app-settings:
```

Is there a way of appending a path to this to link to a specific area of your settings bundle if you have sub-pages?

iOS5 used to have things like this:

```
prefs:root=General&path=Network
```

But various combinations I've tried haven't been successful.

Comment: Upvote! Start a bounty please ;-)